# Как сделать таймер в Python для цикла while, чтобы он не блокировал остальной код (discord bot python)

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Я сейчас делаю бота для дискорда, который будет обновлять статистику моего сервера через цикл while.

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer
import time

client = discord.Client() #Новый объект 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 game = discord.Game("gte!help")
 await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=game) #Вид активности
 print("Бот начал шалить на аккаунте {0.user}".format(client)) #Сообщение о запуске
 time_r = 30
  while True: #цикл
  server1 = MinecraftServer.lookup("тип это не пиар")
  status = server1.status()
  channel = client.get_channel(айди канала)
  await discord.VoiceChannel.edit(channel, name = "Людей на сервере: {0}".format(status.players.online))
  a = a+1
  print(f"Обновлено ", a, " раз")
  time.sleep(time_r) #ожидание
  

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.author == client.user:
  return #Чтобы бот не тригерился на свои сообщения

 if message.content.startswith("gte!stop"):
  await message.channel.send("Остановка бота...")
  exit() #неработающая часть кода из-за цикла

client.run("токен")
```

То есть. Если я сделаю такой цикл, то бот не будет реагировать на команду gte!stop.
Как исправить?

Comment: Создать второй поток который будет за это отвечать вам не подходит?

Comment: Ну могу попробовать. (если честно - не дружу с мультипотоками)

Comment: Возможно не правильно понял проблему, но если вместо `time.sleep(time_r)` поставить `await asyncio.sleep(time_r)` - блокировки не будет